# $S^n$ is topologically homogeneous???

Tags: general-topology

Definition: A set $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is topologically homogeneous if for every $x,y \in X$, there exists a homeomorphism $f: X \to X $, such that $f(x)=y$.

The exercise is to prove that the sphere $S^n = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}: \vert\vert x \vert \vert = 1\}$ is topologically homogeneous.

My attempt:

Let $a,b \neq P \in S^n$, where $P=(0,0,...,1)$.

I can use the stereographics projection $S: S^{n}- \{P\} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and the translation $T_{S(b)-S(a)}:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, that is,  $T_{S(b)-S(a)}(x) = x + S(b) - S(a)$. Of course that $S$ and $T_{S(b)-S(a)}$ are homeomorphism. Then we have the homeomorphism $ S^{-1} \circ T_{S(b)-S(a)} \circ S: S^n - \{P\} \to S^n - \{P\}$ and  $S^{-1} \circ T_{S(b)-S(a)} \circ S(a) = b$

But, when $a= P$ or $b=P$, can you help me?

Comment: I'm surprised that nobody spoke more about your attempt. It is a very nice idea. Once $a=P$, just do stereographic projection from the south pole, and if you want a homeomorphism interchanging those two, do stereographic from the "east pole" if you like. '

Comment: However, it might be a good idea to use the $SO(3)$ idea, since all possible diffeomorphisms (and homeomorphisms) [are intimately related to this matrix group](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2033664?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

Answer (score 2):

And what about considering a linear isometry that maps $x$ to $y$? You can use Gram Schmidt to generate orthonormal bases.

Comment: That's ok, you considerate $x \in S^n$ a vector of a basis and you can take the change of basis to $y$. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Consider $x,y \in S^n$ as vectors. They span a $2$-dimensional subspace, say $Q$, let $Q^{\perp}$ denote the orthogonal complement. Let $\varphi$ be the angle between $x$ and $y$. Now you can define a map $f: S^n \rightarrow S^n$ by decomposing each point into the $Q$ and $Q^{\perp}$ component, the $Q$ component is rotated by $\varphi$, on the $Q^{\perp}$ component $f$ acts as the identity. Then $f$ is an isometry with $f(x)=y$.

Answer (score 0):

The intuition here is this:

First, notice that $x$ and $y$ always lie on a common great circle $C$. If you consider the line through $x$ and the origin, and the line through $y$ and the origin, you get some angle $\theta$ between them moving from $x$ to $y$.

You want to pierce the sphere with a line that is normal to the plane containing $C$, and then rotate your sphere about this line by an angle of $\theta$. This will carry $x$ to $y$, and rotation is a homeomorphism (even an isometry!).

---

From here, you can attempt to formalize the intuition.

As in quarague’s answer (and using their notation) we can take the plane containing $C$ as the plane spanned by $x$ and $y$ to be $Q$, so that $Q^{\perp}$ is exactly our axis of rotation. Then we have a linear transformation that fixes the $Q^{\perp}$ component and rotates the $Q$ components by our angle $\theta$.

Or, you can recall that rotations of the sphere are exactly what $SO(n)$ describes, and so you should be looking for a linear map taking $x$ to $y$. By definition of $SO(n)$, we want $n$ orthonormal vectors involving $x$ and $y$. Gram-Schmidt is exactly the process that helps us find them.

---

Here’s an exercise for you: prove that $S^n$ is actually $k$-homogeneous for all $k\le n$. That is, you can pick a pair of $k$ points $x_1,\dots,x_k$ and $y_1,\dots,y_k$ and find an isometry that takes $x_i$ to $y_i$ for all $i$.